# GitLab Maven Docker Pipelien fails during Docker build

Tags: java, docker, maven, gitlab

I would like to build a Docker image with a GitLab CI Pipeline from a Maven project but the build fails and I don't know what to do.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8
ENV EXECUTABLE_APP_JAR=hello-spring-boot-exec.jar
COPY /target/${EXECUTABLE_APP_JAR} /app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"] 
EXPOSE 7001
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:stable

# Define the stages that will be executed in the pipeline
stages:
- build
- package

# Define global variables
variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: >
-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository
--global-settings $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML_GITLAB_PACKAGE_REGISTRY
cache:
  key: global-maven-repository-cache
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

# Define the job that will build the Maven project
maven-build:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean deploy -e"

docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
    - docker info
    - docker build -t gitlab.my-domain.local:5000/spring-boot-hello-world:latest .
    - docker push gitlab.my-domain.local:5000/spring-boot-hello-world:latest
```

Problem is that the stage docker-build does not find the artifcats from the previous maven-build stage which were build under $CI_PROJECT_DIR/target:

```
#4 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 93b345e2-1ada-4609-9021-058007df7967::r3cqfb3qtqoee8maxyaqmtsnv: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount881123238/target: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount881123238/target: no such file or directory
```

As you can see the docker-build stage is not in the $CI_PROJECT_DIR directory - how can I tell the docker-build stage to take the artifacts from that directory?

Comment: What stage of the `docker build` does it fail on? Why is the `EXPOSE` after the `ENTRYPOINT`?

Comment: You're right, EXPOSE after ENTRYPOINT is wrong.
Build fails during the call of docker build -t gitlab.my-domain.local:5000/spring-boot-hello-world:latest .

Comment: I meant what stage of the Docker build. :)

Comment: Ah ok :). I don't know - where can I see that?

Comment: I don't remember how to see it in Gitlab-CI. Buf if you were to run the `docker build ` command manually in the same environment you should see it. There should be a way in Gitlab CI as well though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I found the solution - I had to add artifacts under the maven-build-stage in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
# Define the job that will build the Maven project
maven-build:
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8
stage: build
script: "mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean deploy -e"
artifacts:
  paths:
    - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/target/*-exec.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that during the Docker build process, a reference with a specific ID was being processed, and Docker attempted to calculate a checksum for it. However, the process failed because Docker was unable to find a directory or file at the given path (`/var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount881123238/target`). This can happen due to various reasons, such as incorrect paths specified in your Dockerfile, missing files, or issues with the Docker build context.

Comment: The OP already found a solution and posted an answer so I don't see how your "answer" adds anything, especially since it is more of a comment than an answer because it just suggests what things to check in order to find the cause of the problem.